# Hibernate Cache com select count

Tags: query, hibernate, cache, count, jpql

Olá!

Tenho uma consulta JPQL, com `count`:

```
public Long quantidadeFaturasAbertasAssinante(Integer idAssin){     
   return manager.createQuery("select count(f) from Fatura f where f.dataLiquidacao IS NULL and f.assinante.id = :ass", Long.class)
            .setParameter("ass", idAssin)                
            .getSingleResult();    

}
```

Ao ser executada a primeira vez após iniciar o tomcat trás o valor correto.
Então altero alguma data de liquidação direto no banco, mas o valor sempre continua o mesmo enquanto não reinicio o tomcat.

É como se estivesse em cache, mas já limpei o cache do hibernate e não muda.
Alguma ideia?

Estou usando a versão 4.3.8 do Hibernate, já tentei mudar para a 4.3.11 e não adianta. Estou usando com JSF primefaces e CDI.

Comment: Você ativou o query cache (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) do Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível resposta para o seu problema é se o [Query Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) está ativado:

```
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
```

Esta configuração cria um cache usando a `String` da consulta e os parâmetros passados. Assim, quando estas duas informações coincidem com o que já está no cache, o Hibernate devolve o resultado pronto direto do cache, sem consultar o banco de dados.

Isto explicaria porque suas alterações no banco de dados não refletem na aplicação.